# how to navigate between directories in absolute path

Tags: linux, macos, unix, gnome-terminal

I am working inside directory with absolute path of  aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff/gg/hh/ii. 
Now I want to jump to a directory dd. I know we can use cd ../.. multiple times to go back, but I want to know is there any faster way?

I am looking for the way something like CMD DIR(which is in PWD ) which will jump to DIR. 
E.G. $ jump dd should result in terminal jumping to aa/bb/cc/dd.

Comment: This should be on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own shell function that looks a bit like this:

```
up() {
    local target dir
    target="$1"
    dir="$PWD"
    while ! [ "$(basename "$dir")" = "$target" ]; do
        dir="$(dirname "$dir")"
        if [ "$dir" = "/" ]; then
            >&2 echo "No such directory found"
            return
        fi
    done
    cd "$dir"
}
```

I have half-heartedly tested this in Bash and Zsh.

If you put this in a file called `up.sh`, you could source that file to get
access to this function. If you want to always have it, you should put it in the
appropriate `rc` file.

Here is some sample usage:

```
$ mkdir -p aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff/gg/hh/ii

$ cat up.sh
up() {
    ...
}

$ source up.sh
$ cd aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff/gg/hh/ii
$ up xyz
No such directory found

$ up bb
$ pwd
.../aa/bb
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is the exact solution I was looking for. can I also ask one more thing from you, I use CSH, or TCSH mainly, can you please tell me how to implement the same?